# How to know that this is the last iteration of a function

Tags: javascript, flotr

I am having the below function which represents X axis of a Chart.

Currently, in this function, 'n' has many iterations which present 0, 25, 50, depending upon the values selected dynamically.

Is there any possibility by which we can know if this is the last iteration of n?

```
xaxis: {showLabels: true, noTicks: 7,tickFormatter: function(n)
{
    var k = n;

    if(k==7) // This is not working
        return NewdateData[NewdateData.length-1]; 
    else  
        return NewdateData[k];      
}
```

Comment: what i am trying to achive is that if it is the last itertaion then i want the last element of an array otherwise continue with the coming values

Comment: @user663724 Could you show a short example of how you call your function and what the expected output is? Edit: I'm sorry, I did not realize that you are using a library. Also, could it be that n is 0-indexed and that the last tick is 6?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply , This is very big code , cant paste it here , i am using http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index to display     HumbleFinance.graphs.price = HumbleFinance.KiranGraph(this.NewData.slice(xmin, xmax+1), newBounds);

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't find any official way to do this, but you might be able to patch the js file to store the noticks calculation result in a variable or, maybe better, send a second parameter to the tickFormatter which is true if it is the last tick.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing your function to a minimum works well comparing `n` with `this.noTicks`:

```
var xaxis = {showLabels: true, noTicks: 7,tickFormatter: function(n){
    return n === this.noTicks;
}};
console.log(xaxis.tickFormatter(1)); //false
console.log(xaxis.tickFormatter(7)); //true
```

Are you calling it the same way, `... .xaxis.tickFormatter(...)` ?

Comment: this code doesn't suit my code, anyway thank you for your help .

Comment: How do you call `tickFormatter`?

Comment: var p = Flotr.draw(
              $('priceGraph'),
              [data],
              {
              
               
               lines: {show: true, fillColor:"#FF6600", fill: true, fillOpacity: .1, lineWidth: 1},
                  yaxis: {min: ymin, max: ymax},
                  xaxis: {min: ymin, max: ymax,showLabels: true, tickFormatter: function(n)
          {
                    if(n)
     {
     return NewdateData[Math.round(n)]; 
     }
     else
     return NewdateData[NewdateData.length-1]; 
     
     
     },

Comment: Not easy then. I would add a `debugger`, and hope to find something while inspecting the variables available at the breakpoint. `tickFormatter: function(n) { if(n) { debugger; return NewdateData[Math.round(n)]; }`